# RewriteEngine producing recursion, altough NS (nosubreq) is specified - Why?

Tags: apache, http, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have this rewriterule:

```
RewriteRule ^authenticate   /id/authenticate.php [NS,QSA]
```

I am getting this error:

> [Sat Jul 23 05:12:37 2011] [error] [client 62.178.15.161] Request
>   exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable
>   configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the
>   limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer:
>   https://2x.to/id/authenticate

I thought the NS flag should prevent this from happening.

Is it not working for some reason, did I not apply it correct or did I misunderstand its purpose?

Is there another way to make this rewriterule "work" without renaming the file?

Edit:

I adapted the RewriteRule to:

```
RewriteRule ^authenticate$  /id/authenticate.php [QSA]
```

which works just fine. However I am still interested in why NS didnt work.

Comment: If you can edit Apache's config files, enable rewrite debugging (`RewriteLogLevel 9`) and check rewrite log to see what is exactly going on. The `[NS]` flag will definitely not help here. This rule on it's own will not produce rewrite loop -- possibly you have some other rules, maybe in htaccess in `/id/` folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want `[L]` here, not `[NS]` -- `[NS]` is specifically for suppressing the rewrite in some unusual situations where Apache will make an "internal" request to itself, like while processing server-side includes.

You may also need to make the rule more specific -- depending on where this rule is, it's possible that `^authenticate` is matching `/id/authenticate.php`. If that's the case, you'll need to add an earlier rule which "carves out" an exception for that file, like this:

```
RewriteRule ^/id/authenticate\.php$ - [L]
```

Comment: the L flag was what came to my mind too, but it wasn't effective. +1 for the rest!